# Data gets corrupted when posting

Tags: php, curl

I've got two subdomains, admin.xxx.com (server 1) and ressource.xxx.com (server 2)

Server 1 has a PHP-script that dynamically generates and writes a Javascript-file, based on some parameters. This part works fine, using the PHP-command "file_put-contents()"

I need to write the javascript file to server 2, that is, same domain, different subdomain; didn't succeed with any cross-domain writing, so I used this CURL-code to submit it serverside, making the file "write.php" on server 2 catch it and write it to disk on behalf of server 1:

```
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "http://ressource.xxx.dk/write.php");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "asset=".base64_encode($asset));

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

This partly works. It generates the file, containing the javascript but the code gets corrupted for several lines

```
<param name="'+aed+'" value="'¥õ•±Í•íÙ…Èhõ¡È¤íh¹Í•Ñ (15 lines of garbage)
```

and then becomes readable again in the end.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why are you encoding it using base 64?

Comment: What is `$asset` set to? What's the source of `write.php`?

Comment: base64 is used as an alternative for escaping the whole thing. The JS-code contains several ampersands and other special characters that potentially could cause undesired effects.

Comment: ampetamachine, $asset contains the Javascript-code for writing - or isn't that what you meant? Write.php simply contains a "if (file_put_contents("test.js", base64_decode($_REQUEST['asset']))) { echo "Success"; } else { echo "Fail"; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL encode the base64 data the way your doing it.  Base64 strings can contain the "+", "=" and "/" characters.  This could mess up the post parameters being sent.

```
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "asset=".urlencode(base64_encode($asset)));
```

If you're base64 encoding it to try and protect if for transfer, you won't need to do this is you urlencode it.

```
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "asset=".urlencode($asset));
```

Another option is to not send a string, but an array for the post fields.  Then curl will do the encoding for you:

```
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("asset" =>$asset));
```

Comment: The first solution did the trick. Now, it writes flawlessly. Thank you, Ray.

Comment: @Anders no problem, but personally, I'd go with the third option.  Let curl do the work for you!

Comment: Yes, you're right - I just learned that all the plus-signs were removed if I used the first approach. The third one worked as a charm.